# httpclient GetAsync doesn't work for large content

Tags: c#, http, xamarin, get

I am trying to download the string content from an endpoint in question using xamarin and http requests. The endpoint I'm supporting with python flask, as well as the content of the page, which is similar to this:

```
[{"name":"test1","timestamp":12312,"type":"ultrasonic","value":65535}, 
{"name":"test2","timestamp":3123123,"type":"ultrasonic","value":65535}...]
```

When there are not many lines in the content of the page, I can access the content and save it to a file inside the android device. When the content is very long, with many lines, the application simply closes.

My code is as follows:

```
public async Task<string> GetNews()
{
    List<string> valores = new List<string>();    
    var response = await client.GetAsync(get_url);    
    var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();    
    string nome = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");    
    //creating the subsequent file
    string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
        "Sensor File - " + nome + ".json");
    //inserting the content of the GET into the generated text file
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, responseData);
    return null;
}
public async void Download_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await GetNews(); 
        //informing in the first label the directory of the saved file
        lb.Text = "File saved successfully!";
    }
    catch
    {
        lb.Text = "Connection not possible, enter the correct URL.";
    }
}
```

I did add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to each await line, but it didn't work... What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried adding any exception handling or crash logging?  Exactly how large is "large" content?  Which specific line causes the crash?

Comment: No, I didn't... I'm new with c#, how can I do that? 
Well... If I try to download a 5KBs content, no problem, it works like a charm... However, If I try to download a 2MB content, the line  "var response = await client.GetAsync(get_url);" fails.

Comment: add a try/catch block to catch the exception and see what specifically causes the failure

Comment: the error is: Java.Net.ProtocolException: 'unexpected end of stream', in line "var response = await client.GetAsync(get_url);"

Comment: there are many existing questions on that error - see https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+unexpected+end+of+stream+java+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: I can't find this error related to my case =/

Comment: did you try the suggestions in the *very first link*?

Comment: yes, didn't work

Answer (score 1):

When you used `HttpClient` to download large amounts of data (50 megabytes or more), then the app should stream those downloads and not use the default buffering. If the default buffering is used the client memory usage will get very large, potentially resulting in substantially reduced performance.

You could try to get the response body and load into memory.

```
using (var response = await client.GetAsync(get_url))
    using (Stream streamToReadFrom =
        await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
            ...........
            //string fileToWriteTo = Path.GetTempFileName();
            //using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(fileToWriteTo, FileMode.Create))
            //{
            //    await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo);
            //}
    }
```

Comment: @wendy-zang-msft I have the same problem, and it's with the `GetAsync` method, not with the `ReadAsStringAsync`. Do you have any other ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Toni yes, you need to use GetAsync(String, HttpCompletionOption) overload with option HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync#system-net-http-httpclient-getasync(system-string-system-net-http-httpcompletionoption)
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption